# Cross-venue visitor reporting approach in Location Based Service system

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, redis

I'm finding an approach to resolve cross-venue vistor report for my client, he wants an HTTP API that return the total unique count of his customer who has visited more than one shop in day range (that API must return in 1-2 seconds).

The raw data sample (...millions records in reality):

```
--------------------------
 DAY | CUSTOMER   | VENUE
--------------------------
  1  |  cust_1    |  A
  2  |  cust_2    |  A
  3  |  cust_1    |  B
  3  |  cust_2    |  A
  4  |  cust_1    |  C
  5  |  cust_3    |  C
  6  |  cust_3    |  A
```

Now, I want to calculate the cross-visitor report. IMO the steps would be as following:

Step 1: aggregate raw data from day 1 to 6

```
--------------------------
 CUSTOMER | VENUE VISIT
--------------------------
   cus_1  | [A, B, C]
   cus_2  | [A]
   cus_3  | [A, C]
```

Step 2: produce the final result

```
Total unique cross-customer: 2 (cus_1 and cus_3)
```

**I've tried somes solutions:**

1. I firstly used MongoDB to store data, then using Flask to write an API that uses MongoDB's utilities: aggregation, addToSet, group, count... But the API's response time is unacceptable.
2. Then, I switched to ElasticSearch with hope on its Aggregation command sets, but they do not support pipeline group command on the output result from the first "terms" aggregation.
3. After that, I read about Redis Sets, Sorted Sets,... But they couldn't help.

*Could you please show me a clue to solve my problem.*

**Thank in advanced!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with Elasticsearch by leveraging one `date_histogram` aggregation to bucket by day, two `terms` aggregations (first bucket by `customer` and then by `venue`) and then only select the customers which visited more than one venue any given day using the [`bucket_selector` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html). It looks like this:

```
POST /sales/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "customers": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "customer.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "venues": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "venue.keyword"
              }
            },
            "cross_selector": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "venues_count": "venues._bucket_count"
                },
                "script": {
                  "source": "params.venues_count > 1"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the result set, you'll get customers 1 and 3 as expected.

**UPDATE**:

Another approach involves using a [`scripted_metric` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) in order to implement the logic yourself. It's a bit more complicated and might not perform well depending on the number of documents and hardware you have, but the following algorithm would yield the response 2 exactly as you expect:

```
POST sales/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "params._agg.visits = new HashMap()",
        "map_script": "def cust = doc['customer.keyword'].value; def venue = doc['venue.keyword'].value; def venues = params._agg.visits.get(cust); if (venues == null) { venues = new HashSet(); } venues.add(venue); params._agg.visits.put(cust, venues)",
        "combine_script": "def merged = new HashMap(); for (v in params._agg.visits.entrySet()) { def cust = merged.get(v.key); if (cust == null) { merged.put(v.key, v.value) } else { cust.addAll(v.value); } } return merged",
        "reduce_script": "def merged = new HashMap(); for (agg in params._aggs) { for (v in agg.entrySet()) {def cust = merged.get(v.key); if (cust == null) {merged.put(v.key, v.value)} else {cust.addAll(v.value); }}} def unique = 0; for (m in merged.entrySet()) { if (m.value.size() > 1) unique++;} return unique"

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took": 1413,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "unique": {
      "value": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Val, Thank for your quickly help. But I want only the unique count result (in this case: 2 unique count) because the customer bucket result list may be 50k of records. So I don't want to extract this bucket json and get its length to return that number in my API. Is this possible?

Comment: In that case, another approach would involve using a [`scripted_metric`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) aggregation in order to spit out that figure. Definitely doable I think.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide a second alternative

Comment: I very much appreciated your help! Now I can produce the result I want in sub-seconds response time.